# PostSharp community edition

Tags: .net, aop, postsharp

What is and is not included in the Community Edition?  How do I separate the community edition from the paid edition?  It seems like they are bundled together?

Comment: I did. I also searched "community" in the documentation.  Can you find something that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Compare PostSharp Editions](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/purchase/compare)

From the [FAQ](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/purchase/faq):

> **Can I use the Community Edition for commercial products?** Yes. You can
>   build commercial products using the
>   Community Edition and redistribute
>   them. However, if you are serious
>   about aspect-oriented development,
>   consider using the Professional
>   Edition. Your software will be faster
>   at run time and you will be more
>   productive during development.

Comment: thanks!  I didn't think to click "purchase" to find out what's free.

Comment: @SFun28
: yeah, 'Purchase' not the most obvious place I have to admit!